# Use of Bernouli's equation in Water Rocket calculations

Tags: bernoulli-equation

In calculating the exit velocity of the water in a water rocket, all the sites I have found use Bernoulli's equation in the rockets frame of reference. I know that that is correct if the rocket was an inertial frame eg being held at rest or moving with a constant velocity. However the rocket is being accelerated or put another way is not being held fixed in the inertial frame. I think that makes a differece. If I was standing in the rocket's frame I would feel very heavy. ie I experience a higher g force than normal. So I rather think that the exit velocity of the water is higher than is being calculated but I do not know how to do that. Can anybody tell me I am wrong or direct me to a link that addresses this?

Here is an example link
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243714323_Soda-bottle_water_rockets

Comment: Can you link to one of the derivations you found?  It may be that the derivations are correct if the calculation at a particular time $t$ is being done in the inertial reference frame moving with the rocket at that same time $t$.

Comment: I have added the simplest link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue here is that the usual Bernoulli equation, that
$$
\frac 12  |{\bf v}|^2 +\frac{P}{\rho} +gh
$$
is constant along a steamline,
does not apply when the velocities of the water is time dependent. Instead, for irrotaional flow where ${\bf v}=\nabla \phi$, Bernoulli  becomes
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} +\frac 12  |{\bf v}|^2 +\frac{P}{\rho}+gh
$$
is constant.  Also you are right in that the "$g$" in the above equation  will  be that felt in the acclerating frame: $g\to g+a_{\rm rocket}$.  That extra will tend to "pull" the water out of the rocket in addtion to the "push" from the air.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link where I can read more?

Comment: The Bernoulli equation with the exra term is discussed in chapter 1 of our book "mathematics for physics" (published by Cambridge University Press)  . A draft free-to-read version is at  https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf

Comment: That is extremely helpful and generous. Thank you.